# How to show related items using DeleteView in Django?

Tags: django, view, cascade

I am doing a view to delete (using the generic view DeleteView from Django) an instance from a model, but it cascades and deletes instances from other models:

```
url(r'^person/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', login_required(DeleteView.as_view(model=Person, success_url='/person/', template_name='delete.html')), name='person_delete'),
```

What I want to do is to show the list of related items that are going to be deleted, as the admin interface does, like:

```
Are you sure you are going to delete Person NAMEOFTHEPERSON?
By deleting it, you are also going to delete:
CLASSNAME1: CLASSOBJECT1 ; CLASSNAME2: CLASSOBJECT2 ; CLASSNAME3: CLASSOBJECT3 ; etc
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use the [`Collector`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py) class Django uses to determine what objects to delete in the cascade. Instantiate it and then call `collect` on it passing the objects you intend to delete. It expects a list or queryset, so if you only have one object, just put in inside a list:

```
from django.db.models.deletion import Collector

collector = Collector(using='default') # or specific database
collector.collect([some_instance])
for model, instance in collector.instances_with_model():
    # do something
```

`instances_with_model` returns a generator, so you can only use it within the context of a loop. If you'd prefer an actual data structure that you can manipulate, the `admin` contrib package has a `Collector` subclass called [`NestedObjects`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/util.py), that works the same way, but has a `nested` method that returns a hierarchical list:

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects

collector = NestedObjects(using='default') # or specific database
collector.collect([some_instance])
to_delete = collector.nested()
```

Updated: Since Django 1.9, *django.contrib.admin.util* was renamed to *django.contrib.admin.utils*

Comment: Note that Collector does not resolve many-to-many fields, you need to use NestedObjects to do that.

Answer (score 7):

I use a cutdown modifcation of get_deleted_objects() from the admin 
and use it to extend my context in get_context in the delete view:

#### define somewhere

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
from django.utils.text import capfirst
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

def get_deleted_objects(objs): 
    collector = NestedObjects(using='default')
    collector.collect(objs)
    #
    def format_callback(obj):
        opts = obj._meta
        no_edit_link = '%s: %s' % (capfirst(opts.verbose_name),
                                   force_text(obj))
        return no_edit_link            
    #
    to_delete = collector.nested(format_callback)
    protected = [format_callback(obj) for obj in collector.protected]
    model_count = {model._meta.verbose_name_plural: len(objs) for model, objs in collector.model_objs.items()}
    #
    return to_delete, model_count, protected
```

#### then in your views

```
from somewhere import get_deleted_objects
#
class ExampleDelete(DeleteView):
    # ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #
        deletable_objects, model_count, protected = get_deleted_objects([self.object])
        #
        context['deletable_objects']=deletable_objects
        context['model_count']=dict(model_count).items()
        context['protected']=protected
        #
        return context
```

#### now you can use them in your template

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  {% for model_name, object_count in model_count %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ model_name|capfirst }}</td>
      <td>{{ object_count }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
<p>
  <ul>
    {{ deletable_objects|unordered_list }}
  </ul>
</p>
```

#### Most is just copy/paste/edit/delete unwanted from django admin

Comment: get_context should be get_context_data

Comment: This works fine. On a many to many with self referencing, to_delete contains also something like 'From_company-to_company relationship: Company_contractor object (13)'. How to show properly also this kind of relationship?