# How can I check what objects will be cascade deleted in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

In the /admin/ section of Django you can choose to delete items.

If any related objects would be deleted along with your chosen object you get to see a list of affected objects before you confirm delete.

Can I check this in my own function programmatically?

I'd like to do something like

```
for item in Item.objects.all():
    if not deletion_would_also_delete_other_objects(item):
        item.delete()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show related items using DeleteView in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158714/how-to-show-related-items-using-deleteview-in-django)

Answer (score 28):

Could you use from django.db.models.deletion import Collector to do this?

```
from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
from .models import Item
  
for item in Item.objects.all(): 
    collector = Collector(using='default')
    collector.collect([item])

    # dependencies should be an empty dict if the item is not related to anything
    if not collector.dependencies:
        item.delete()
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string` on `collector.collect([item])` in Django 1.9. This is fixed if I specify the `using` parameter when instantiating the Collector: `collector = Collector(using='default')`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is accurate (at least anymore). I found `.dependencies` was empty, but `.data` and `.fast_deletes` both showed lots of objects that would be deleted.

Comment: Indeed, both pieces of information from the previous 2 comments should be included in the answer.

Comment: According to the comments in the code [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py], `.fast_deletes` only includes things that do not cascade, and it looks like `.data` just contains the values of the collected objects themselves. so i think the post as updated is correct.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest using the `NestedObjects` util provided in django admin.

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
from django.db import router

using = router.db_for_write(Item._meta.model)
# if you only have one database, just set using = "default"

nested_object = NestedObjects(using)
nested_object.collect([Item])
# If you want to delete multi item, you can use:
# nested_object.collect(Model.objects.filter(type="deleted"))

print(nested_object.nested()
```

The result look like this:
[image: example result]

Comment: I find this the most convenient way of getting the desired result, because all data is aggregated in one place, and it's much easier to parse a nested list, than several independent dicts (as when using `Collector`).