# Django List objects that will be deleted by deleting the current object

Tags: django, django-models

In my DeleteView template, I'd like to warn the user that deleting the current object will delete the following objects (since the db schema requires `on_delete = models.CASCADE`).

Here is an example model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name = 'course_books', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name = 'exercises', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    ...

class Solution(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name = 'solutions', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
```

So, say the user wants to delete a course, I'd like to warn the user which books, exercises, and solutions will be deleted upon deleting the current book. Something to this effect:

```
WARNING: Deleting course Programming 101 will delete Python Programming for Beginners and Python By Example.  It will also delete Excersises 1-5 and solutions 1-10
```

This will require that I can look at the related field to see if the on_delete is set to CASCADE or not.  If it is, I should add it to the list of to_be_deleted objects.

I have looked to see if I can check the on_delete attribute of the field:

```
for related_object in the_course._meta.related_objects:
    dir(related_object.field)
```

But nothing shows up to help so I'm reaching out here...

Answer (score 7):

You can do so doing

```py
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

collector = NestedObjects(using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS)
collector.collect([obj])
print(collector.nested())
```

Comment: I had to move to another part of the project. I am revisiting the DeleteView and ran your code. When I type `the_project = Project.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'some_name')` I get `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` I did run `help(collector.collect)`, and it does say that I have to pass QuerySet to it, but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the objects with that particular `object_id`. For example:

```
qs = Solution.objects.filter(exercise__book__course_id=course_id).select_related('exercise__book')
```

This will give a queryset of all the objects of Solution with related foreign key objects `exercise` and `book`. Then you can loop through this queryset and check `instance._meta.app_label` to differentiate between the objects.

Comment: This solution works but it is a way around solution because you would have to know the related object and do all the work by hand. On a site where the relationships are across multiple apps, it is not practical. So, your solution is much appreciated and helpful, but I will wait for another solution for now

Comment: ok then you should edit your question so that it will be active again, otherwise it won't get enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a duplicated question with [How can I check what objects will be cascade deleted in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807858/how-can-i-check-what-objects-will-be-cascade-deleted-in-django). So I paste the same answer:

I suggest using the `NestedObjects` util provided in django admin.

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import NestedObjects
from django.db import router

using = router.db_for_write(Item._meta.model)
# if you only have one database, just set using = "default"

nested_object = NestedObjects(using)
nested_object.collect([Item])
# If you want to delete multi item, you can use:
# nested_object.collect(Model.objects.filter(type="deleted"))

print(nested_object.nested()
```

The result look like this:
[image: example result]