# How to find all Django foreign key references to an instance

Tags: python, django

How do you find all direct foreign key references to a specific Django model instance?

I want to delete a record, but I want to maintain all child records that refer to it, so I'm trying to "swap out" the reference to the old record with a different one before I delete it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158714/how-to-show-related-items-using-deleteview-in-django) similar question references the Collector class. I tried:

```
obj_to_delete = MyModel.objects.get(id=blah)
new_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=blah2)
collector = Collector(using='default')
collector.collect([obj_to_delete])
for other_model, other_data in collector.field_updates.iteritems():
    for (other_field, _value), other_instances in other_data.iteritems():

        # Why is this necessary?
        if other_field.rel.to is not type(first_obj):
            continue

        for other_instance in other_instances:
            setattr(other_instance, other_field.name, new_obj)
            other_instance.save()

# All FK references should be gone, so this should be safe to delete.
obj_to_delete.delete()
```

However, this seems to have two problems:

1. Sometimes `collector.field_updates` contains references to models and fields that have nothing to do with my target `obj_to_delete`.
2. My final `obj_to_delete.delete()` call fails with IntegrityErrors complaining about remaining records that still refer to it, records that weren't caught by the collector.

What am I doing wrong?

I just need a way to lookup all FK references to a single model instance. I don't need any kind of fancy dependency lookup like what's used in Django's standard deletion view.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Django's reverse foreign key support.

Say you have two models, like so:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Bar(models.Model):
   descr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Then you know you can do `bar_instance.foo` to access the Foo object it keys to. But you can use the reverse foreign key on a `Foo` instance to get all the `Bar` objects that point to it using, e.g, `foo.bar_set`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the best option is to avoid the cascaded deletion.

Declaring the foreign keys in the related models with the proper Django option, e.g.

```
on_delete=models.SET_NULL
```

should suffice.

Borrowing the sample models from @Joseph's answer:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Bar(models.Model):
   descr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL))
```

As described in the official [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), here are the predefined behaviours you can use and experiment with:

- SET_NULL: Set the ForeignKey null; this is only possible if null is
  True.
- SET_DEFAULT: Set the ForeignKey to its default value; a default for
  the ForeignKey must be set.
- SET(): Set the ForeignKey to the value passed to SET(), or if a
  callable is passed in, the result of calling it. In most cases, passing a callable will be necessary to avoid executing queries at the time your models.py is imported:

> ```
> from django.conf import settings
> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
> from django.db import models
>
> def get_sentinel_user():
>     return get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]
>
> class MyModel(models.Model):
>     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
>                              on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
> ```

- DO_NOTHING: Take no action. If your database backend enforces
  referential integrity, this will cause an IntegrityError unless you
  manually add an SQL ON DELETE constraint to the database field