# Retrieve objects about to be deleted in cascade in django

Tags: python, django

Considering those classes:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

class Baz(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class XXX(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(field_related_to_FOO_somehow)
...
```

Given an instance `foo=Foo.objects.get(...)` that a user want to delete, i want to provide him a view of all the objects he's about to delete. Thus, how can i retrieve all the instances of `Bar`, `Baz` and all other related objects `XXX` that will be deleted in cascade if the user confirm?

Comment: Could you use the same function as the django admin uses?
https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L119

Comment: Here's a similar question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158714/how-to-show-related-items-using-deleteview-in-django

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)

bar = Bar.objects.filter(foo=foo)

baz = Baz.objects.filter(bar=bar)

baz.delete()
bar.delete()
```

or just

```
foo.delete()
```

Comment: I don't want to delete things but know what will be deleted. I don't want to declare explicitely the related objects but want to be generic and retrieve all the related objects recursively

Comment: you just delete foo - at the moment you run foo.delete() all the children will be gone

Comment: That still doesn't work since i'm considering the moment before the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`
this will set None when delete related objects.

[docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)