# Recursive delete foreign keys for Django object

Tags: python, django, recursion

Suppose I have an object called Person that has a foreign key that links to CLothes which links to

```
class Person(models.Model):
    clothes = models.ForeignKey('Clothes', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    jokes = models.ManyToManyField(to='Jokes')

class Clothes(models.Model):
    fabric = models.ForeignKey('Material', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Material(models.Model):
    plant = models.ForeignKey('Plant', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And if I wanted to delete person, I would have to delete Clothes, Jokes, Materials attached to it. Is there a way to recursively detect all the foreign keys so that I can delete them?

Comment: Why don't you use `on_delete=models.CASCADE`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Well I would but in this instance, the code base is written by someone else and I need to find a way to override the `on_delete` signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `django.db.models.deletion.Collector` is suited for this task. It is what Django uses under the hood to cascade deletions.

You can use it this way:

```
from django.db.models.deletion import Collector

collector = Collector(using='default')  # You may specify another database
collector.collect([some_instance])
for model, instance in collector.instances_with_model():
    # Our instance has already been deleted, trying again would result in an error
    if instance == some_instance:
        continue
    instance.delete()
```

For more information about the `Collector` class, you can refer to this question:

[How to show related items using DeleteView in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12158714)

As mentioned in the comments, using `on_delete=models.CASCADE` would be the best solution but if you do not have control over that, this should work.