# How to modify a queryset and save it as new objects?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to query for a set of objects for a particular Model, change a single attribute/column ("account"), and then save the entire queryset's objects as new objects/rows. In other words, I want to duplicate the objects, with a single attribute ("account") changed on the duplicates.  I'm basically creating a new account and then going through each model and copying a previous account's objects to the new account, so I'll be doing this repeatedly, with different models, probably using django shell. How should I approach this?  Can it be done at the queryset level or do I need to loop through all the objects?

i.e.,

```
MyModel.objects.filter(account="acct_1")
# Now I need to set account = "acct_2" for the entire queryset, 
# and save as new rows in the database
```

Comment: I think I'm confused.  Do you want to duplicate the objects, and set a new account to them?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I'll try to reword it to make it clearer.

Comment: You can bulk update, and you can bulk insert, but you can't bulk update and create new in a single line. You have to loop through the queryset.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshSmeaton . Looks like bozdoz's answer is the way to go then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert):

> If the object’s primary key attribute is not set, or if it’s set but a
>   record doesn’t exist, Django executes an INSERT.

So if you set the `id` or `pk` to None it should work, but I've seen conflicting responses to this solution on SO: [Duplicating model instances and their related objects in Django / Algorithm for recusrively duplicating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437166/duplicating-model-instances-and-their-related-objects-in-django-algorithm-for)

This solution should work (thanks @JoshSmeaton for the fix):

```
models = MyModel.objects.filter(account="acct_1")
for model in models:
  model.id = None
  model.account = "acct_2"
  model.save()
```

I think in my case, I have a `OneToOneField` on the model that I'm testing on, so it makes sense that my test wouldn't work with this basic solution.  But, I believe it should work, so long as you take care of OneToOneField's.

Comment: but that would save over the old objects, would it not?

Comment: Yes.  I was confused by the question. Apologies @BenRoberts

Comment: This will override the field.

Comment: You just need to set the id to None, I've updated your answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in my version of django, but I see from other questions that it should work in others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database