# How to duplicate a record with all dependencies?

Tags: django

In my Django app I have a model and there is another model that refers as Foreign key to my model.

For example:
Order - the parent model 
Items -  as a child in that order.

What is the easy way to implement functionality for end users  to duplicate my order in a way that also all children will get duplicated as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you want to make clone of model instance. Then you can read [related documentation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances). Also there are a couple of answers on SO related: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234986/duplicate-django-model-instance-and-all-foreign-keys-pointing-to-it), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733609/how-do-i-clone-a-django-model-instance-object-and-save-it-to-the-database), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975000/3606603)

Comment: Yes, model instance but not just from the particular  model but also all models under it.