# Is there an equivalent for _collect_sub_objects method in Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to implement a method that duplicate Django model instances and its related objects. The solution is in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437166/duplicating-model-instances-and-their-related-objects-in-django-algorithm-for).

But `_collect_sub_objects` method seems to be deprecated in recent versions of Django. Somebody could tell me if its an equivalent in recent versions of Django?

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with python 3; that was a Django method that was removed in Django 1.3, which is nine versions ago.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, I updated the question.