# Create a Django Admin Action to Duplicate a Record

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create a Django Admin Action that allows me to create a duplicate of a record.

Heres the use case.

Admin clicks the checkbox next to a record in an app that they want to duplicate.
Admin selects "Duplicate" from the admin action drop down menu.
Admin clicks go.
Django admin creates a duplicate record with a new id.
Page is refrshed and new duplicate is added with id.
Admin clicks on the new, duplicated record, and edits it.
Admin clicks save.

Am I crazy or is this a pretty straight forward Admin Action?

I've been using these docs for reference: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

I'm thinking something like this:

In my app:

```
def duplicate(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    new = obj.id
    queryset.create(new)
    return None
duplicate.short_description = "Duplicate selected record"
```

I know that's not right... but is my thinking close?

Comment: it's not an action, but you can get a 'save as' link in the edit form this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180809/in-the-django-admin-interface-is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-an-item

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the right idea but you need to iterate through the queryset then duplicate each object.

```
def duplicate_event(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for object in queryset:
        object.id = None
        object.save()
duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplicate selected record"
```

Comment: Now the trick is, how to also duplicate any FK models that point to this model.

Comment: Remember to also add the duplicate action to the actions list in the MyappAdmin class for your application Myapp:

    actions = [duplicate_event]

Comment: To copy FK and M2M read [link](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/rprasad/2012/08/24/using-django-admin-to-copy-an-object/)

Comment: Is possible do it compatible with mptt ??

Comment: This approach will not copy relations, using save_as is a way better approach that copies model including relations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180809/in-the-django-admin-interface-is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-an-item

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work to for you.

```
def duplicate_query_sets(queryset, **kwargs):
    for p in queryset:
        p.pk = None
        for i, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(p, i, v)

        p.save()
```