# Django admin action to duplicate a record and edit it

Tags: django

I know how we can add an action to duplicate a record as explaind below:
[Create a Django Admin Action to Duplicate a Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989894/create-a-django-admin-action-to-duplicate-a-record)
To edit the added record one must find and edit it manually.
I'd like to know how we can edit the added record as a part of this action ie. the action saves the record and calls the change view for this record(save and edit)

Comment: Hi user2012749 - could you mark my answer as correct, so that this question is marked as answered? Stackoverflow relies on this mechanism, and it's considered rude not to get a correct answer and not formally recognise it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to do if there are multiple added records. However, for the single case, you could just do a redirect to the admin page. You need to see the section in the docs about showing further pages:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages

You'll need to do a redirect to edit the newly created object. Combined with the duplicating code, it's going to look something like:

```
def duplicate_records(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    object_ids = []
    for object in queryset:
        object.id = None
        object.save()
        object_ids.append(object.id)

    if len(object_ids) == 1:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:yourapp_yourmodel_change', 
                                    args=(object_ids[0],))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:yourapp_yourmodel_changelist')
            + "?id_in={0}".format(",".join(str(i) for i in object_ids))
```

This code is untested, and you'll need some imports, but it should work. For the multiple object case, it's supposed to redirect to a changelist page that shows just the created objects.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I need only the single object case but I will try for the multiple case also.